# 7-Zip: Unsupported Compression Method while trying to extract a zipx file that consists of JPEGs

Tags: windows, compression, 7-zip, jpeg

A zipx file I received consists of .csv files and .jpeg files. I used 7-zip to extract them. While the .csv files were sucessfully extracted, the JPEG files didn't. The error was something like this

> Unsupported Compression Method for C:\\314567.jpeg

Comment: try the latest 7-zip Alpha:http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/07d5c851/

Comment: didn't see your comment there @magicandre1981. Will try it!

Comment: update to current 7-zip http://www.7-zip.org/download.html
do not use the older 9.2 version, use the ones at the top

Answer (score 2):

Use WinZip or Bitzipper to extract that file. (You can also try updating 7zip to the latest version if not already).

It looks like zipx is a format with a couple of newer compression algorithms.

> ZIPX (.zipx) is a file extension for a compressed file that can be created/opened with WinZip (they first introduced the format) or Bitzipper. A Zipx file is basically a zip file but created using advanced compression methods, supported in the latest version of WinZip and also by other zip utilities (Bitzipper is the latest one to add ZIPX support). Because of these new compression methods introduced by WinZip, zipx is practically the smallest zip files up to date.

http://www.zipxfile.com/

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo! Winzip was perfect. Any idea why 7-zip failed here?

Comment: Then mark it as answered. =)  My guess is that the archive was compressed using a very specific (and maybe proprietary) algorithm that only WinZip and Bitzipper are currently using.